# Latest libraries for jQuery drag drop

Tags: jquery

I have a website which uses drag drop. At the moment I use

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Which ones are needed, and can someone explain the difference between

- jquery.min.js
- jquery-ui.min.js
- jquery-ui.css (I guess its for the design of jQuery function?)

And can I use different versions of them or do I need to use the same version.

**1.9.1**/jquery.min.js
and
**1.10.1**/jquery.min.js

At the moment dropable isn't working in ie10 but i want to see if the version of jQuery makes any difference.

Comment: Jquery and JQuery UI are two completely different projects, so the numbering on these two projects have no relevance to each other. Whats the actual problem you're having with IE10? Perhaps it has nothing to do with the version of the libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) are two entirely different projects.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/):
jQuery is javascript library which provides easy and browser compatable dom manipulation, traversl, ajax etc. It has no dependency with jQuery UI.

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/): 
It is a provides a rich set of user interface tools like datepicker, drag-drop etc, it depends on jQuery project.

In your case you can use jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.1 without any problems